# How to get parameters values in view component?

Tags: parameters, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I have created view component and sent 2 arguments to it.

```
<vc:ModalComponent>
    title = "Create"
    id = "createModal"
</vc:ModalComponent>
```

How do I get the `title` and `id` values from the view component?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If the community is to help you we need a) what you expect to see, b) what you are seeing, c) any error messages. Please edit the question to clarify these points.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your code, I assume you defined a ViewComponent with name `ModalComponent`.

I suggest you follow steps below:

- ViewComponent like below:

  ```
   public class ModalComponent : ViewComponent
  {
      public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync(
              string title, int id)
      {
          return View(new { Title = title, Id = id });
      }
   }
  ```
- Create your view in path `Views/<controller_name>/Components/<view_component_name>/<view_name>` or `Views/Shared/Components/<view_component_name>/<view_name>`
- Invoke ViewComponent

  ```
    <vc:modal-component title="title1"
                 id=2>
    </vc:modal-component>
  ```

**Note**

- You need to use `modal-component` for `ModalComponent`
- You need to set variable with attribute in `<vc:modal-component`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access data send to a ViewComponent in its Invoke method.
E.g.

```
public IViewComponentResult Invoke(string title, string id)
{
    //do sth here
    return View();
}
```